# Absolutely Positioned Images - No Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlap

I'm using JS masonry to absolutely position images on a page, and I'm using some JS to give each image a random margin-top and margin-left to give the effect of random spacing etc. However some of the images overlap. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

You can see the current outcome here: http://richgc.com/freelance/staton/exhibitions-installations/

Thanks,
R

Comment: Since you're lazy-loading the images, you have to force a relayout in masonry every time a new image loads. Otherwise, it will distribute the elements based on the side of your placeholder.

Comment: You could use `$(this).prev().height()` and add the previous images `height` into the equation - you may find you also need to take it's `margin-top` into the calculation too.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah so this wouldn't happen if I didn't use lazyload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @bfavaretto's suggestion, the issue was that masonry and lazyload don't go hand in hand, so I added a callback to masonry to reload everytime you scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
    $container.masonry();
}, 0);
```

});

The only issue is that I bet the load on the page is mega now, so any improvements are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Although this adds a few bugs when you reach the bottom of the page. Any suggestions?